# Extracting from a Nested list Using Indexing and slicing

Tags: list, indexing, slice

here is my current list: [0, [], [1,2,3,4], [[5],[6,7]], [8,9,10]]
want to extract from the list and nested items using indexing and slicing, this is what I want to extract: [0, 2, 3, [5 ,6], 8, 10]

code so far:

```
    list = [0, [], [1,2,3,4], [[5],[6,7]], [8,9,10]]
new_list = list[0], list[2], list[3], list[4]
print("new list is", new_list)
```

outputs this: new list is (0, [1, 2, 3, 4], [[5], [6, 7]], [8, 9, 10]), need to extrac tthe nexted items and format the list like this: [0, 2, 3, [5 ,6], 8, 10]

Answer (score 0):

```
L = [0, [], [1,2,3,4], [[5],[6,7]], [8,9,10]]
new_list = [L[0], L[2][1], L[2][2], [L[3][0][0], L[3][1][0]], L[-1][-3], L[-1][-1]]
print("new list is", new_list) 
print()
```